# Booking link in company profile

Tags: hyperlink, schema, profile, google-schemas

I noticed that when you search on google certain restaurants, it appears with a link to book the restaurant in restorando.cl just like this:

[Company profile with link embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z33ej.png)

It is possible to have something similar to book sport courts? I work on a company that i have lots of sports complexes to book and I want to know if it's possible to implement a direct link to the booking process on our app / website.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Mr. Rebot, actually there's no error or code used... I just want to know if there's a way to embed a link like the one in the picture attached to book a sports court.